# Sorting array list method is to slow

Tags: android

First to say that I see very similar questions but i think this is not duplicate.

I need to sort string array list where members of list are in format `ID::NAME` and where `ID` is some number and `name` some string.

First idea was simple I use

```
ArrayList<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();
my_list.add("0" + "::" + "ABC");
my_list.add("2" + "::" + "DBC");
my_list.add("1" + "::" + "DDC");
my_list.add("10" + "::" + "DBD");
my_list.add("22" + "::" + "DDD");
(etc...)
Collections.sort(my_list);
```

Problem is that in this method of sort `"10" + "::" + "DBD"` are before `"1" + "::" + "DDC"` etc I get something like:

`0::ABC`,
`10::DBD`,
`1::DDC`,
`22::DDD`,
`2::DBC`

And what i need is :

`0::ABC`,
`1::DDC`,
`2::DBC`,
`10::DBD`,
`22::DDD`

After this I try to make some temp integer list where i get all `ID`, sort this list , compare numbers with spliced value in `my_list` and get name from my list , to be clear this is code:

```
ArrayList<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> sortedlist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> sortedTempIdlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

my_list.add("0" + "::" + "ABC");
my_list.add("2" + "::" + "DBC");
my_list.add("1" + "::" + "DDC");
my_list.add("10" + "::" + "DBD");
my_list.add("22" + "::" + "DDD");
sortedTempIdlist(0);
sortedTempIdlist(2);
sortedTempIdlist(1);
sortedTempIdlist(10);
sortedTempIdlist(22);

Collections.sort(sortedTempIdlist);
for (int i = 0; i < sortedTempIdlist.size(); i++) {
    String temp = my_list.get(i);
    String[] s;

    try {
         s = temp.split("::");
         String name = s[1].toString();
         String id   = s[0].toString();

         for (String x : my_list) {
             Integer compare = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(x.split("::")[0]));
             if (sortedTempIdlist.get(i) == compare) { 
                  sortedlist.add(String.valueOf(sortedTempIdlist.get(i)) + "::" + String.valueOf(x.split("::")[1]));
             }
          }

    } catch (Exception e) {};
}
```

Now this work and sort list is ok but problem is that this work to slow when i have to many list member(lets say 600 or 1000).
Is there faster way for something like this?

Thanx

Comment: why don't you wrap the id and string in a small object, and use Collections.sort(), with a comparator to sort the list against the id? Collections.sort() is O(nlogn)

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanx! I try your method,and work like charms.:)

Comment: Maybe better answer , if somebody more have similar problem, solution is great.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the id and the String in a small object:

```
public class Item {
   public int id;
   public String name;
}
```

and use `Collections.sort()` to sort the list agains the id:

```
Collections.sort(listInstance, new Comparator<Item>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
           return lhs.id < rhs.id ? - 1 : (lhs.id == rhs.id ? 0 : 1) ;
     }
 });
```

`Collections.sort()` will sort your list in `O(nlogn)`